# undo-tree output like git log

Tags: undo, undo-tree-mode

I just discovered `undo-tree-mode` and it's amazing. 
My use case is finding changes that I've made before so that I can re-apply them. However I'm having difficulty finding the changes I've made.

Is there an easy way to get output like `git log -p` or better `git log -p  --graph` from this so that I could grep it? The existence of `undo-tree-visualizer-toggle-diff` suggests that most of the code to do this is already there.

Answer (score 1):

[Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit/) can do this. From `M-x magit-status` show the log by pressing `l` then `-g` to turn on the graph and `-u` to show the diffs / patches. Then you can search as normal with `C-s` etc.

Comment: That's pretty cool. The advantage of undo tree (and it's disadvantage) is that the 'commits' are created automatically.